# FluentNHibernate and custom TableNameConvention

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

**FluentNHibernate version 1.3.0.727**

I have the following custom TableNameConvention:

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.TableName, Is.Not.Set);
    }

    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name + "s");
    }
}
```

I have the following entity mapping:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Email).Not.Nullable().Length(200);
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Length(100);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Length(100);
        Map(x => x.Password).Not.Nullable().Length(30);
    }
}
```

I'm generating database like this:

```
var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
        .AddFromAssemblyOf<IEntity>()
                              .Conventions.Add<TableNameConvention>())
        .BuildConfiguration();

var schema = new SchemaExport(configuration);
schema.Drop(false, true);
schema.Create(false, true);
```

Then generating database User entity table is still generated as User but not Users as I want it to be. It seams that Accept method fails. Is this FluentNHibernate bug?

Comment: btw `schema.Drop(false, true);` is redundant since Create will always drop before create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code

```
public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
{
    criteria.Expect(x => x.TableName, Is.Not.Set);
}
```

because it is not needed and maybe even not what you want. FNH has three values internally for each property (e.g. tablename)

1. value set explicitly in classmap
2. value set by convention
3. defaultvalue

and it uses what it finds in this order `valueInEffect = explicitValue ?? conventionValue ?? defaultValue`

Comment: How could I check if table name value is set explicitly in classmap?

Comment: you don't need to since the value from the convention is overridden by the value from the classmap, see the pseudocode in the last sentence